Hibernate filter activate/deactivate before/after FetchType.LAZY
I would like to understand more about Filters in Hibernate and their effect when they are activated/deactivate before/after Lazy collection load.
Here is simple DB diagram:

Lets say we have Java @Entity for User, Role and Car. They are connected with JoinTable user_role. Most important here is User class.
User class
@FilterDef(name="carsByUserRole", parameters={
        @ParamDef( name="role_id", type = org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.IntegerJavaType.class)
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String surname;    

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "user_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"
            ),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "role_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"
            ))
    @FilterJoinTable(name="carsByUseRole", condition="role_id = :role_id")
    private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();

Without @Filter the JoinTable for ArrayList cars would return all cars associated via join table for any role for that user. If I use filter like this:
Filter filter = session.enableFilter("carsByUserRole");
    filter.setParameter("role_id",1);
    user.getCars().forEach(car -> {
        System.out.println("Cars for role_id 1 : "+car.getName());
    });
    session.disableFilter("carsByUserRole");

    user.getCars().forEach(car -> {
        System.out.println("Cars for all roles? : "+car.getName()); //will return same result as get() in filter section
});

First I will get all cars for that user only for role_id = 1 in filter section. But then I do another user.getCars() AFTER filter section and it gives me same result as in filter section. I though that session.disableFilter("carsByUserRole") will disable filter and next user.getCars() will fetch that data again from DB. But it doesnt.
How to refresh fetched data in user.getCars() call? Or how filters works? Are they one way call and then I must fetch root object again from DB to call another filter variable?
